# convert time to based on each timezone in KDB+

Tags: kdb

| timeStamp | timeZone | localTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022.10.06D08:56:00.508000000 | "Europe/London" | localTime to London |
| 2022.10.06D08:56:00.508000000 | "Australia/Sydney" | localTime to sydney |
| 2022.10.06D08:56:00.508000000 | "America/New York" | localTime to new york |

I want to convert timeStamp of each timeZone to its local time.

```
update localTime:{first (dxTZFromGMT[`$y;timeStamp])} each timeZone from table
```

I am able to convert to only single timeZone

```
update localTime:{first (dxTZFromGMT[`$"Australia/Sydney";x])} each timeStamp from table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update localTime:first each dxTimeZone'[`$timeZone; timestamp] from table
```

`'` form of each https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each

```
{show (x;y)}'[1 2 3;4 5 6]
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: required result shouldn't be a list type ```localTime:,2022.10.06D08:38:11.238000000``` since its a column in a table

Comment: required result should look like localTime:2022.10.06D08:38:11.238000000

Comment: Edited answer with `first each` to account for `dxTimeZone` always returning a list